# Corda standalone shell - execute command without entering into shell

Tags: corda

The --help of Cords Standalone Shell says the following:

```
corda-shell [-hvV] [--logging-level=<loggingLevel>] [--password=<password>]
        [--sshd-hostkey-directory=<sshdHostKeyDirectory>]
        [--sshd-port=<sshdPort>] [--truststore-file=<trustStoreFile>]
        [--truststore-password=<trustStorePassword>]
        [--truststore-type=<trustStoreType>] [--user=<user>] [-a=<host>]
        [-c=<cordappDirectory>] [-f=<configFile>] [-o=<commandsDirectory>]
        [-p=<port>] [COMMAND]
```

Now I was thinking that after specifying the appropriate parameters I can specify the [COMMAND] which I want to be executed on the node (e.g. run gracefulShutdown) but I cannot find a way to do that with standalone shell. Is there a way to do that or may be I am on wrong direction?
P.S. I need to drain and shut down the node before deploying the new cordapp in my CI/CD flow, thats why I need run gracefulShutdown.

When I try to run a command using this technique I get the following error:

```
Unmatched argument: help
Did you mean: install-shell-extensions?
```

Comment: So are you getting an error, or nothing is happening? I never tried to include the command; I usually started the node shell, then typed the command. I assume that you want to automate that using a shell script?

Comment: I have edited the question. I guess I am in wrong direction. I need to create a RPC client java program myself I guess which will gracefully shut down node. 
Yes I have a CI/CD which automates deployment, but it does not respect the fact that while deploying the node can have ongoing flows running. I need to add this support in my CI/CD

Answer (score 2):

**Method-1** -- Submit/STDIN the commands via pipe.

```
echo -e "run nodeInfo\nexit"|java -jar corda-tools-shell-cli-4.8.7.jar \
--truststore-file /$PWD/certificates/export/rpcssltruststore.jks \
--truststore-password=apple -p=10006 -a localhost \
--user user1 --password=test
```

**Method-2** -- Text the commands in a file and provide it as STDIN

```
]$ cat /tmp/commands 
run nodeInfo
exit
]$ java -jar ~/bin/es/corda-tools-shell-cli-4.8.7.jar --truststore-file /$PWD/certificates/export/rpcssltruststore.jks --truststore-password=rpctruststorepassword -p=10006 -a localhost --user user1 --password=test < /tmp/commands 
   ______               __
  / ____/     _________/ /___ _
 / /     __  / ___/ __  / __ `/ 
/ /___  /_/ / /  / /_/ / /_/ /
\____/     /_/   \__,_/\__,_/
--- Corda Enterprise Edition 4.8.7 (8baf4b1) ---

Standalone Shell connected to localhost:10006


Welcome to the Corda interactive shell.
Useful commands include 'help' to see what is available, and 'bye' to exit the shell.

Tue Jul 26 16:01:16 SGT 2022>>> run nodeInfo
addresses:
- "localhost:10005"
legalIdentitiesAndCerts:
- "O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB"
platformVersion: 10
serial: 1658810279418


Tue Jul 26 16:01:16 SGT 2022>>> exit
Have a good day!

]$
```

**Important** is to ensure and keep exit at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first enter into the shell to be able to issue commands to the node. The [COMMAND] parameter is probably a little misleading, The only command it has is  'install-shell-extension' which just adds an alias so that the jar can be run using a suitable name like 'corda-shell'.